# Besides endic.naver.com, any other good Korean-to-English dictionary site for (hangul) super-newbie learners?

Tags: vocabulary, resources, study-technique

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Main_Page) is great for super-newbie learners of Hangul.

For example, see this question re: 기계 (gigye)  : [기계 (gigye) ==> 機械, 器械, 奇計 (what else?)](https://korean.stackexchange.com/q/2021/544)

What's another good Korean-to-English dictionary site for (hangul) super-newbie learners (who know English) ?

Is there something like [Jisho](https://jisho.org/) for Japanese ?

[Search result for 'gigye' Naver English-Korean Dictionary](https://en.dict.naver.com/#/search?range=all&query=gigye).

I don't even understand what this result (above) is showing, and it's not much use to me without the Chinese characters anyway.  Thanks !

This [result from endic.naver.com](http://endic.naver.com/search.nhn?sLn=kr&searchOption=all&query=%EA%B8%B0%EA%B3%84) is better.

Comment: Thanks for splitting this question out. Why do you mention the [search for (Romanised) 'gigye'](http://endic.naver.com/search.nhn?sLn=kr&searchOption=all&query=gigye)? Are you looking for a dictionary where you can search for Romanised Korean words?

Comment: @topomorto the two never examples suggest they are probably looking for one with Hanja

Comment: It seems you know Japanese. Would a Korean-Japanese dictionary server better for you? After all not every Korean word has a corresponding Hanja form, so you can't solely rely on that.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I immediately went and looked for such a  Korean-Japanese dictionary  on the net, but I couldn't find any.  Maybe there'll be something within a few years.  Thanks again! --

Answer (score 3):

I recommend [dic.impact.pe.kr](http://dic.impact.pe.kr) it's pretty good and easy to understand.

The cool part is that it also searches for your input in translated sentences so you can figure out how a word is actually used.