# What does 남달라 mean in EXO's Tempo?

Tags: translation, lyrics

Short question: I came across 남달라 when reading/trying to translate the [lyrics of EXO's Tempo](https://gasazip.com/2266375)... I went to Papago translate and google translate but seems very difficult to get results from them... what does it mean? and thank you very much... :)

Comment: links to the lyrics? What exactly was the difficulty while translating? Did it give any error? What was the error message? Do you have a dictionary? We have a couple of dictionary suggestion related questions on this site: https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/1815/what-is-a-good-digital-korean-english-dictionary, https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/2023/besides-endic-naver-com-any-other-good-kor-eng-dictionary-site-for-hangul-su?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

남달라 = 남다르다 adjective : It is quite different (다르다) from other (남).

His interest to the art is quite deep 그의 미술에 대한 관심은
남달라.

He showed a outstanding talent in music 그는 음악에 남다른 재능을
보였다.

@ We can compare 남다르다 with "strange" or "weird". But in my thought, 남다르다 is used almost in positive feeling.

그 장군은 어렸을 때 참 기괴했어. 아니 남달랐다가 더 정확하겠네.

The general was weird in childhood. No, 남다르다 is more accurate.

Answer (score -1):

남달라 : unusual, uncommon, unique

Comment: Can you expand upon this answer? How is the word being used specifically in this context?