# What's the meanings of 다구리, 뭉쳐, 스릉 and so on?

Tags: korean-to-english

How do you say this in English?
1- 하지만 어떻게 해야 이기는지 알아
2- 다구리다
3- 뭉쳐
4- 스릉
5- 뒈질래

Comment: Have you referred a dictionary? https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/2023/besides-endic-naver-com-any-other-good-kor-eng-dictionary-site-for-hangul-su, https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/1815/what-is-a-good-digital-korean-english-dictionary

Comment: 1. But I know how to win 2. Bully 3. Gather 4. ??? 5. Do you wanna die? As a native I don't know whar #4 means.

Comment: Isn't one of the foremost rules of the foreign language SE sites "we are not a translation service"?

Comment: @temporary_user_name the guidelines for this site are at  https://korean.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic - Perhaps ideally this kind of question would be asked as up to 5 separate questions, with a bit more context added.

Comment: now i see korean slangs are difficult to understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** But, I know how I win

**2.** 다구리 noun, 다구리다 = 그것은 다구리 입니다.

It is a handling-way.
 Usually, in action movie, or crime event, to overcome a fixed man, 다구리 is a *several people's beating*.

**3.** 뭉쳐 : Largely, there are two means. 눈을 뭉쳐 press snow into a lump/make
a snowball.

And it has a mean 협동(cooperation) : 뭉치면 살고 흩어지면 죽는다
united we stand, divided we fall.

**4.** 스릉 = 사랑, 스릉한다 I love you. It is recent new word. When we shut up and pronounce 사랑, it is similar to 스릉.

**5.** Do you want to die ?

There are many expression about death 돌아 가시다 = opposite to return (=돌아 오다).

When a honorable man die, we want that he would return to our real
world. Hence when he die, we express 돌아 가시다.

On the other hand, there is 뒈지다, which describes a death of bad
guy. For instance, 저 인간 언제 뒈지냐 ? I want that he would die.

When some animal die, then it shows his belly. That is, it is
flipped. (뒈지다 is a short of 뒤집어 지다).

Answer (score 1):

1.하지만 어떻게 해야 이기는지 알아

`But I know how to win`

2.다구리다

`It's not an official word, but it is used when a group of people pick on a single person.`

3.뭉쳐

`gather around`

4.스릉

`you say this when you say "사랑" or love with your teeth together, so not a real word.`

5.뒈질레

`a bad meaning for death. isn't used when you actually wanna kill someone, but when someone makes you feel pissed off.`