# Korean dictionary (online or offline) showing the pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation, resources

Do you know any dictionary of Korean showing the pronunciation of each word like the example below? That would be a great resource.

까맣다 **[까ː마타]**

Another question: is there any equivalent version of [toPhonetics](https://tophonetics.com/) (formerly lingorado.com) for Korean?

Comment: Regarding lingorado.com, can you create a separate question for that? Also, can you include a brief description of the site, as I could not grasp it from a quick look at it since it is Russian (I think).

Comment: Thanks for the perfect answer for dictionary. It is a very good dictionary! For the second question, I've just edited the link. However, as you said maybe it is better to make a new thread for that. The online converter of English text to IPA phonetic transcription will translate English text into its phonetic transcription using International Phonetic Alphabet. So I am looking for a similar page that will translate Korean text into its pronunciation form. For example: 까맣다 --> [까ː마타] but this should work for a sentence or paragraph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[*The National Institute of the Korean Language's Basic(/Learner's) Korean Dictionary*](https://krdict.korean.go.kr) has pronunciation for each word in both written and audio form. For example, here is their entry for [까맣다](https://krdict.korean.go.kr/eng/dicSearch/SearchView?ParaWordNo=64358&nationCode=6&nation=eng&captchaNumber=&comment_user_name=&wordComment=&viewTypes=on&myViewWord=64358):

[image: 까맣다 basic entry]

This is my prefered dictionary for this because not only is it available for their basic Korean dictionary, but also for all their translated learner's dictionaries (something the other's don't have; see below). See my other [answer](https://korean.stackexchange.com/a/2720/691) for a more 
complete review of this dictionary.

---

[Naver's Korean Dictionary](http://krdic.naver.com/) (not Korean-English dictionary) also shows the pronunciation guide along with audio; however, when I just checked, the audio was not working.  Here is their entry for [까맣다](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=6097200):

[image: 까맣다 naver entry]

---

Daum is like Naver, and only shows it for their [Korean dictionary](http://alldic.daum.net/index.do?dic=kor), but at least their audio works. Here is their entry for [까맣다](http://alldic.daum.net/word/view.do?wordid=kkw000038569&supid=kku000052947):

[image: 까맣다 daum entry]

Answer (score 1):

To share, I know of an offline app resource called Beginner Korean (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shex.beginnerkorean) that is meant to help you learn the common Korean words, their meanings and pronunciation.

The only trouble with this 'solution is, you'd have to learn from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

The mobile version of the Naver Korean-English dictionary for learners also contains audio for words. You can access it from the web [here](https://korean.dict.naver.com/english).

[image: naver dictionary]