# How do say and spell "Epiphany" in Korean

Tags: meaning

I was trying to learn new words and when I was searching in translators they put this 출현, but I don't know, it was a different meaning of the real Epiphany one, can you guys help me with this?

Comment: what translator did you use? What was the result? Why do you think it was wrong? Have you tried a more reliable dictionary like naver or google translate? Please add these details to your question. Google translate easily gives me epiphany for 출현.

Comment: Please have a look at the links here for online resources for learning Korean: https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/537/websites-and-internet-resources-for-learning-korean, https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/1815/what-is-a-good-digital-korean-english-dictionary?rq=1, https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/2737/korean-dictionary-online-or-offline-showing-the-pronunciation?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @user17915 ...and it would be wrong. No meaning of 출현 I know of has any overlap with the meaning of _epiphany_. In general, I think it's a terrible advice to ask users of this site to try Google translate. It's very hit-and-miss, and when it's wrong, the only possible explanation is "Well, what did you expect from Google Translate?"

Comment: If by *epiphany* you mean *realisation*, I think the best translation is 깨달음. 출현 (出現) looks like the earlier Christian/religious definition of the word (*A manifestation or appearance of a divine or superhuman being*). Would you mind clarifying in the question what you mean by *epiphany*?

Comment: Also, the religious festival Epiphany is called 주현절 in Korean, whose hanja form is 主顯節 (not derived from 출현 / 出現).

Answer (score 1):

Epiphany is said as 에피파니. In general, people do not use this
word, except in a religious context.

1) It is a birthday or appearance (생일 또는 출현) :

My epiphany is 19th Dec. 내 생일은 12월 19일이다. Sometimes musicians
use this so that fan interpret it as a birthday. That is, fan
believe that the musician use that word to elaborate himself with
heroic things.

2) It is realization (깨달음) :

Some singer use this word for title of the song. The lyric explains
that he realizes his soul.