# what does 헌납당했고 mean? I came across it in a novel

Tags: vocabulary

what does 헌납당했고 mean?
I came across this sentence in a novel.

here is the context:

우리는 흡혈의 자유와 반역의 재능을 헌납당했고 대신 생존의 굴욕만을 넘겨받았다.

Comment: have you checked a dictionary? We have a list of digital dictionaries for Korean here: https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/1815/what-is-a-good-digital-korean-english-dictionary?rq=1

Comment: I did and I get what all the words mean but I still feel like I don't understand the sentence.  what HK Lee wrote completely cleared it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 헌납하다 = give money or valuable thing to someone (with no
>   expectation about reward)

나는 전 재산을 국가에 헌납했다.

I dedicate my whole asset to my country.

> 당하다 = receive a bad thing

그의 거짓말에 또 당했다

I was fooled by his lie again.

> 헌납당하다=헌납을 당하다.

그는 전 재산을 국가에 헌납당했다.

Being the opposite to his will, his whole asset is dedicated to his
country.